# Windows 11 - How do I stop resistance between verticle borders for multi-display

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, windows-11

Posting a solution here to save other people headache, because this site doesn't let you comment without reputation ( -_-)

My display arrangement is like this:
[display arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5wr7.png)

I found if I drag 3 or 2 towards bottom display 1, it would never get them perfectly aligned. It felt like the border between 1 and 3 was connected so there would be no mouse resistance. But the border between 1 and 2 was slightly off, so to get the mouse to cross the border you needed to move it quick enough (rage inducing).

Arranging the displays using my mouse would always result in this behaviour, even with minute adjustments.

However if you select display 3, then press the down button key on keyboard, it would go towards display 1 and connect, if you then select display 2 and hit the down key it would also connect.
Now I experience no resistance between all borders, finally it works. I can't believe this issue has annoyed me for so long on Windows. Their display adjustment screen needs some work I think.